# How can I scale up an SVG and save as PNG, with PHP without losing quality?

Tags: php, svg, png, imagick

I have a batch of SVG images that I need to resize and then save as PNG, and I'd like to use PHP to do it. Similar questions to mine have been asked but none of the solutions work for me. For example:

**option A**: use PHP to change the width and height attribute of the SVG.

**problem with A**: this seems to work fine but in fact it only increases the canvas size, not the contents of the canvas. I'm not sure if it's important but my SVGs are small graphics that were created with Illustrator, mostly made up of path elements.

**option B**: use imagick to resize and resave

**example**:

```
$im = new Imagick();
$im->setResolution( $startResolution * ($newWidth / $oldWidth ), $startResolution * ($newHeight / $oldHeight ) );
$im->readImage( $svgSource );
$im->setImageFormat("png32");
echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($im) . '"  />';
```

**problem with B**: this also seems to work fine but the resulting png will be blurry

**option C**: variant of option B, you set the resolution really high, like 5000, then resize.

**problem with C**: the resulting PNG is still blurry

**option D**: use exec(convert...) to get around PHP's bugs

**problem with D**: you guessed it, the resulting PNG is still blurry

Has anyone found a way to make this work?

Comment: Why don't you modify the dimensions in the SVG itself? That's vector based, so should be able to scale up without losing quality (unless you're using images in it). Modify the SVG, save as PNG, done.

Comment: unless I'm misunderstanding you, modifying the SVG itself is the first option I listed. It doesn't work for me because it just increases the canvas size, but not the elements contained within.

Comment: The items within the SVG should also have some data about their sizes,  angles and what not.

Comment: Maybe, but they basically consist of huge strings of numbers, for example: <path ......... d="M-106.276,171.203c-112.4,0-224.799,0-337.199,0 ------------ this string of numbers goes on for hundreds of lines. Can I reliably find the correct number(s) to change, on every path element, in every file I need to modify?

Comment: Hmm, no, that's more difficult. Your option B should work though. Perhaps your calculations for the `setResolution` call produce wrong results?

Comment: I thought that might be the case that's why I tried option C - forget the calculation and just set the resolution to something ridiculous like 5000, then resize and save. But it's still blurry...

Comment: Check out http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For option A:

If the svg expects the coordinate system to be whatever it was when it was created (read: the original width/height), then you will need to add a `viewBox` attribute (use `0 0 originalwidth originalheight`). Then when you set new width and height attributes the svg should rescale itself properly to the new size.

Comment: Thanks @Erik Dahlström, that worked perfectly! My file already had viewBox and I was changing those settings as well, for example width="newWidth" height="newHeight" viewBox="0 0 newWidth newHeight". As soon as I left viewBox unchanged, the rescale was no longer blurry and I was able to export a clear PNG.

Answer (score 1):

I have achived this similar thing using 'batik' library.

I have specifed **'Area of Interest'** which need to be converted to Png.
here's what i have done.

```
    public function makeSvgtoPngImages() {
     $tempSVG_filename = $user_folder_path . 'temp.svg';                   
     $tempSVG_handle = fopen($tempSVG_filename, 'w+');
     fwrite($tempSVG_handle, $user_svg_content);
     fclose($tempSVG_handle);

        $mimetype = 'image/png';
        $width =2000;
        $height=2000;                    
        $area_interest = '472,185,555,275'; 
      // in my case i am using area of interest is my viewBox                   

        $result = shell_exec('java  -jar /var/www/batik-1.7/batik-rasterizer.jar -m ' . $mimetype . ' -d ' . $outputfile . ' -w ' . $width . ' -h ' . $height . ' -a ' . $area_interest . ' ' . $tempSVG_filename . ' 2>&1');

         unlink($tempSVG_filename);


}
```