# php convert svg data to a jpg format

Tags: php, svg, imagemagick, jpeg

I have svg data such as

```xml
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="500" height="500" xml:space="preserve">
   <desc>Created with Fabric.js 1.4.0</desc>
   <defs></defs>
   <g transform="translate(250 250)">
     <image xlink:href="http://arcanumdeepsecrets.files.wordpress.com/2010/06/blast_500x500.jpg" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: ; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(0,0,0); opacity: 1;" transform="translate(-250 -250)" width="500" height="500" preserveAspectRatio="none"></image>
   </g>
   <rect x="-250" y="-250" rx="0" ry="0" width="500" height="500" style="stroke: red; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: 5 5; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: none; opacity: 1;" transform="translate(250 250)"/>
   <rect x="-245" y="-245" rx="0" ry="0" width="490" height="490" style="stroke: green; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: 5 5; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: none; opacity: 1;" transform="translate(250 250)"/>
   <rect x="-240" y="-240" rx="0" ry="0" width="480" height="480" style="stroke: blue; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: 5 5; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: none; opacity: 1;" transform="translate(250 250)"/>
   <polygon points="-25 25,0 -25,25 25" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: ; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: red; opacity: 1;" transform="translate(248 296)"/>
   <g transform="translate(256.5 176.85)">
     <text font-family="arial" font-size="29" font-weight="normal" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: ; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(0,0,0); opacity: 1;" transform="translate(-23.5 28)">
       <tspan x="0" y="-18.85" fill="rgb(0,0,0)">wer</tspan>
     </text>
   </g>
   <g transform="translate(269.04 238.43) scale(2.61 2.61)">
     <text font-family="comic sans ms" font-size="29" font-weight="normal" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: ; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(0,0,0); opacity: 1;" transform="translate(-75 28)">
       <tspan x="0" y="-18.85" fill="rgb(0,0,0)">Some Text</tspan>
     </text>
   </g>
 </svg>
```

That is being posted to me

Im trying to take this data and save it as a JPG format with resolution of 300 (preserving quality) and preserving the external links and fonts being used.

Does anyone know how to do this. I am lost and have no way of knowing where to even start. I have read image magick may be able to do it but have not seen any examples of this.

Comment: An svg image does not have a resolution and it does not make sense to "preserve external links and fonts being used", since raster graphic formats like jpeg cannot store those. You can try using the imagemagick suite (the convert utility) to convert the image to any resolution you want. But the result is a raster graphic, nothing comparable to an svg image.

Comment: so there is no way for me to save this as a jpg with all the images that are referenced to external urls? Also what would the imagemagick command acutally be iv tried looking for it

Comment: As said: raster graphics have no means to store references or the like. It does not make sense in the world of raster graphics. Scalar and raster graphics are totally different universes you cannot simply convert between. Creating a raster graphic from an svg is like making a screen shot. Not more and not less.

Comment: i have already given batik solution to comverting svg to png, have a look at it here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/21179501/2384215 .